# Switchery (Radio button) value to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using the following styled radio button:

[Switchery](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/)

The issue is that the value is 0 by default instead of 1, And when i "OFF" the radio button returns `NULL`.

```
$categoryItem->status = Input::get('status');

<input type="checkbox" name="status" data-render="switchery" data-theme="default" checked="1" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit input code :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" data-render="switchery" data-theme="default" checked="checked" value="1" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;">
```

if checked check box , get value to server side code 1.
if uncheck check box , not sent value for server side.so get response server side POST or GET input=>status undefined or NULL

Comment: And what for `0` ?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="status" data-render="switchery" data-theme="default" checked="" value="1" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;">

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by simple if-else condition.

```
if(Input::get('status') == null){
  $status = 0;
}else{
  $status=1;
}
```